# Does WPA/WPA2 mixed mode have weak security even if I always connect using WPA2-AES?

Tags: wifi, wireless, wpa2

My Wi-Fi access point is in "WPA/WPA2 mixed mode", which allows devices to connect to it using either WPA, WPA2-TKIP, or WPA2-AES. My Apple<sup>®</sup> smartphones and tablet computers are warning that my Wi-Fi has "weak security" because of WPA and WPA2-TKIP. I don't see the issue with the presence of WPA and WPA2-TKIP, since I am always connecting using WPA2-AES. Is my mixed mode Wi-Fi insecure even if I always connect using WPA2-AES?

Comment: Why have it enabled?

Comment: @vidarlo It is not fully within my control. e.g. the access point only supports WPA/WPA2 mixed mode, with no option to enable WPA2-AES only; or the access point is shared with other peoples' devices that require WPA.

Comment: "warning that my Wi-Fi has "weak security"" -- can you provide the full and actual message?

Comment: "I'm using stronger security. Why is the device complaining that there is weaker security?" -- ... because there is weaker security ... "Is my mixed mode Wi-Fi insecure" -- yes, of course. Maybe not for the specific devices using stronger settings, but then what is your question?

Answer (score -1):

The mode is only "mixed" if devices of different wireless generations are connected on the same access point. So your network key is as secure as your weakest (WPA) version device. You can't run WPA attacks on a WPA2/3 client because it's not using WPA even if other devices can or are on that network.

So the answer is yes but with some important distinctions.

Comment: This is not correct. It is "mixed mode" if the AP is set that way, not if the devices connected to the AP are "mixed".

Comment: That's not what I meant of course the AP determines all it's own modes but if no client connects using a particular protocol no attacker can use attacks against that protocol on the network. If there are no WPA clients then there are no feasibly crackable keys being exchanged.

Comment: So, the *mode* is in fact "mixed". An attacker could attack and connect with a weaker device, right? And that weaker device introduces risks to the stronger devices?